# Prove that if two strucutres are not distinguishable then also modifed structures are distinguishable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\mathbb{A}= \langle A, \le_A \rangle$  ,$\mathbb{B}= \langle B,
>  \le_B \rangle$ will be partial orders. Prove that if $\forall_n $ and
>    $\forall_{\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B}}$   $\mathbb{A}\equiv_n \mathbb{B}$
>   then also $\mathbb{A'}\equiv_n \mathbb{B'}$, where $\mathbb{X'}$
>   denotes $\mathbb{X}$ with added the largest element (so to both
>   structure we add per one element such that it is the biggest.

I am trying to prove it using EF-games. From graphical point of view structure is tree - undirected acyclic connected graph.   However, the idea is to use strategy of duplicator for $\mathbb{A}\equiv_n \mathbb{B}$ - let call it as *old* strategy.

If spoiler doesnt pick up the largest element (root of tree) then duplicator uses *old* strategy.  In case of picking up root, duplicator also pick up root.

Why does it work ?
Following *old* strategy duplicator prevent relation between *old* elements. In both structure root is in the same relation between *old* elements it is largest than each *old* element. So if duplicator pick up root iff spoiler do it he manage to win.

What do you think ? Maybe someone can solve it in other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me!

---

There's also a very silly solution via ultrapowers - this is definitely more work than the EF-games solution, so there's no earthly reason why anyone would do this, but I think it's neat so I'll put it here.

**There truly is no good reason to do this at all - I'm honestly just putting it down since I think some readers will find it neat, as I did. It uses nontrivial facts about ultrapowers, so it definitely takes work to follow. Understanding it is *completely unnecessary*, so don't worry if it doesn't make sense yet.**

By the [Keisler-Shelah theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Keisler-Shelah_isomorphism_theorem), since $A\equiv B$ there are ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{V}$ on index sets $I, J$ such that $$\prod_IA/\mathcal{U}\cong \prod_JB/\mathcal{V}.$$ Call these ultrapowers $M$ and $N$ respectively.

Now consider $M'$ and $N'$, built in the same way as $A'$ and $B'$ (just add a new top element to $M$ and $N$, respectively). I claim that $$(*)\quad \quad M'\cong\prod_IA'/\mathcal{U}\quad\mbox{and}\quad N'\cong\prod_JB'/\mathcal{V}.$$ To see why this is enough, let $f: M\rightarrow N$ be an isomorphism; then $f$ extends to an isomorphism $\hat{f}: M'\rightarrow N'$ (this is true for general structures - just map the new top element to the new top element, and otherwise do what $f$ does). By [Los' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#.C5.81o.C5.9B.27s_theorem), if two ultrapowers are elementarily equivalent, then so are the ultraroots (= the structures we're taking the ultrapowers of); since $M'\cong N'$ via $\hat{f}$, we have [a fortiori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_a_fortiori) that $M'\equiv N'$, so this will show $A'\equiv B'$.

So how do we prove $(*)$? I'll show $M'\cong \prod_{I}A'/\mathcal{U}$; the $N'$-version is identical. An element of $M'$ is an equivalence class of a sequence $\alpha=(a_i)_{i\in I}$ with $a_i\in A'$. Now, for such a sequence, let $New=\{i: a_i\mbox{ is the new top element}\}$. Either $New\in\mathcal{U}$ or $I\setminus New\in\mathcal{U}$; if the former holds, then $\alpha$ corresponds to the new top element of $M'$, and if the latter holds, then $\alpha$ corresponds to one of the elements of $M$ (*since $\alpha$ is $\mathcal{U}$-equivalent to some $\beta=(b_i)_{i\in I}$ whose terms all come from $A$: just get $\beta$ from $\alpha$ by changing each of the "new" terms to some random thing from $A$, and however you do this you'll have $\beta\approx_\mathcal{U}\alpha$ since they'll agree on $I\setminus New$, which is in $\mathcal{U}$*). This shows that the underlying *set* of $M'$ is exactly the underlying *set* of $\prod_IA'/\mathcal{U}$, and it's not hard to show via similar reasoning that the natural bijection here is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! 1.To my eye, it is also analogous situation when we add also add the smallest element (so adding the biggest and the smallest).

Comment: @HaskellFun Yup. In general, if we add a fixed number of elements which interact "uniformly" with the existing objects, that will preserve $\equiv$.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe this subject will be intresting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147662/prove-that-formula-in-monadic-second-order-logic-exists-for-each-node-path-is